# Can one bound the Taylor series remainder in terms of bound for the whole Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

I have an function $f$ with a Taylor expansion $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$.

Suppose I write the function in terms of its remainder:
$$f(x) = P_{N}(x) + R_{N+1}(x)$$ where $P_N$ contains all the terms in the Taylor series of $O(x^N)$ and below, and remainder $R_{N+1}(x)$ contains all terms above.

Suppose I have an independently obtained bound $|f(x)| \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty |b_k| x^k$ for all $x>0$.

Can I prove a bound of the form:

$$ |R_{N+1}(x)| \leq  \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |b_k| x^k,$$

(essentially, does the remainder of my upper bound always bound the remainder of the original function)?

Comment: I see no reason why this should hold in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try $f(x) = \sin x$.  Check these details:

The Maclaurin series is
$$
f(x) = x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+O(x^5)
$$
It is known that
$$
|f(x)| \le 1\qquad\text{for all } x .
$$
So we can use $b_0=1$ with $b_k = 0$ for all $k \ge 1$ to achieve
$$
|f(x)| \le |b_0|+|b_1| x + |b_2| x^2 + \dots\qquad \text{for all } x.
$$
Consider $P_2(x) = x$ and $R_3(x) = \sin x - x$.  However, we do not have
inequality
$|P_3(x)| \le |b_3|x^3+\dots$  That is, we do not have $|\sin x - x| = 0$.

In fact, we do not even have $|R_3(x)| \le 1$.